# Missing rules: "L'ecologia" Clementoni

Tags: house-rules

I have an old copy of "L'ecologia" of "I giochi di Sapientino" by Clementoni.

Unluckily the instructions are missing.

Can anyone help?

Comment: You might want to try reaching out to that company and they might be able to quickly help you with the rules. It might be hard for this site to find rules for an Italian game

Answer (score 2):

I found the contact form from the company: https://www.clementoni.com/it/slug-assistenza-form/

I presume you should be good enough with Italian to be able to file in an enquiry to ask them if it would be possible to download the PDF manual.